# csv.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: [constant] is not defined

Tags: javascript

Here is the entire code:

```
function id(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/);
      resolve(parsedLines);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', getReleasesFromFile);

function getReleasesFromFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  if (file === undefined) return

  parseFile(file).then(idsDirty => {
    const idsClean = idsDirty.filter(id => id.trim().length > 0)
    buildDocument(idsClean)
    console.log(idsDirty)
    console.log(idsClean)
  });
}

function parseFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      parsedLines = e.target.result.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/)
      resolve(parsedLines)
    }
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}

async function buildDocument(idsClean) {
  const releaseData = []
  for (const id of idsClean) {
    const data = await getRelease(id)
    releaseData.push(data)
  }
  const text = releaseData.join('\n')
  saveCsv(text, 'output')
}

;(async function ( ) {
  const idsClean = []
  const accessInterval = 2400;
  let lastRequest = new Date - accessInterval;
  if(idsClean !== undefined) {
    for ( const id of idsClean ) { // Wait until one has passed since the previous request was initiated
      await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, lastRequest + accessInterval - new Date() ) );
      try {
        lastRequest = new Date;
        const release = await getRelease( id );
      } catch ( err ) { // Handle request failure here,
        // Depending on the error, perhaps add another delay and retry
        // or loop up to some limit retrying on each iteration, increasing the delay each time you get a 429 error
        // At a minimum just log the skipped release id with console.log( id );
      } // end of catch
    } // end of for loop
  } // end of if statement
} )(); // end of async

function getRelease(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'CSVforDiscogs/0.1',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseReleaseData)
  }

    function parseReleaseData(data) {
      if (data.message === 'Release not found.')
      return `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist`

      const id = data.id
      const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : []
      const title = data.title || []
      const format = data.formats[0].name || []
      const format_qty = data.formats[0].qty || []
      const format_descriptions = data.formats[0].descriptions || []
      const format_descriptions_formatted = format_descriptions.map(description => description.replace(/"/g, "\"\""))
      const label = data.labels[0].name || []
      const catno = data.labels[0].catno || []
      const identifiers = data.identifiers[0] || []
      const barcode = data.identifiers.filter((item) => item.type === 'Barcode')
      const barcode_values = barcode.map(barcode => barcode.value)
      const country = data.country || 'Unknown'
      const released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown'
      const genres = data.genres || []
      const styles = data.styles || []
      const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : []

      return [id, artists, title, label, catno, barcode_values, format, format_qty, '"' + format_descriptions_formatted + '"',
      country, released, '"' + genres + '"', '"' + styles + '"', '"' + tracklist + '"'].join(',')
    }

    function saveCsv(text, fileName) {
      const csvData = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${text}`
      const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvData)
      const hiddenElement = document.createElement('a')
      hiddenElement.href = encodedUri
      hiddenElement.target = '_blank'
      hiddenElement.download = `${fileName}.csv`
      document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement)
      hiddenElement.click()
      hiddenElement.remove()
    }
```

I'm just getting...

> csv.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: idsClean is not defined

What really confuses me is that when I comment out the second `async` function I get no errors. So that suggests to me that `idsClean` is fine. (I'm not sure if that is the right constant to enter there, but none of the other possibilities I've tried has worked either.) Any help please? TIA.

Edit: I added `const idsClean = []` into the `accessInterval' section, which cleared the previous error I was having. However I still hit a`429` error whenever I upload a file of 30 or more lines, so I'm not sure if that section is doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: `idsClean` is never neither defined, nor assigned in the code you've posted. Regardless whether it "works" or not, It's just an error, unless it's defined somewhere else.

Comment: It means that when `buildDocument` is called `idsClean` is defined, but when the second async function is called, `idsClean` is not defined. If this hint has not helped you enough, post more of the code so that we can help more.

Comment: @Teun, thanks, I roughly understand but I'm really not sure how to fix it. I tried 

    `;(async function (idsClean) {
    
      const accessInterval = 1000;
      let lastRequest = new Date - accessInterval;
    
      for ( const id of idsClean )`

...but I'm getting...

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: idsClean is not iterable

Comment: @double-happiness you have now added `idsClean` as a parameter to the function, but looking at the rest of the code `idsClean` is defined outside of the functions. If you can edit your answer and post the rest of the code of your file, we can help you further.

Comment: @Teun - OK, I've pasted the entire code in the OP.

Comment: Okay, so the async function has no way of getting the `idsClean`. The way you have set it up, is that the async function is executed immediately when this file gets imported/called. I think you've to make the function like the `buildDocument` function, call it when you need it instead of immediately, and pass the `idsClean` the same way.

Comment: @Teun - that makes reasonable sense, thanks, but I've really no idea how to do that. I kind of thought `await getRelease( id )` made it wait until `getRelease' was executed.